# Unable to install gcloud SDK

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

When I try to install google cloud SDK, I was getting the following error:

ERROR:

> (gcloud.components.update) Failed to fetch component listing from
>   server. Check your network settings and try again. This will install
>   all the core command line tools necessary for working with the Google
>   Cloud Platform. Failed to install.

After reinstalling python (v3.7.0), I added the path and also added CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to make sure. Now when I attempt the installation, the installation simply hangs:

[image]

If I attempt the installation trough terminal by executing install.bat, it also gets stuck after requesting to send diagnostics to google:

```
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Active code page: 65001

To help improve the quality of this product, we collect anonymized usage data
and anonymized stacktraces when crashes are encountered; additional information
is available at <https://cloud.google.com/sdk/usage-statistics>. This data is
handled in accordance with our privacy policy
<https://policies.google.com/privacy>. You may choose to opt in this
collection now (by choosing 'Y' at the below prompt), or at any time in the
future by running the following command:

    gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting false

Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (y/N)?  n
```

Nothing gets printed after that.

Comment: Maybe try the non-GUI version and see if alternate error messages are reported.  It appears we can run install.bat ... see ... https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#silent

Comment: I did, sorry I just have specified in the question, I have edited it now.

Comment: @guibvieira - If the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63530387/10819573) to your question has worked for you, do not forget to mark the answer as accepted so that future visitors can also use the solution confidently.

Comment: I had the same issue but then I was able to install itt via chocolatey.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the "(gcloud.components.update) Failed to fetch component listing from server" error might be caused by some proxies or antivirus in your environment, I'd recommend you to try a clean installation in a vm or using another network.

Also, I was able to find soem similar errors for this on issue tracker and the team gave a soltion at [comment10](https://issuetracker.google.com/146458519#comment10), also, as you can see on the issue tracker, sometimes this behavior is because the Python SDK is installed on default "Program Files" location, you could give it a try by changing the location of the python SDK

Comment: I did also find that possible solution and attempted python installation on C drive and in Program Files. I also tried using the bundle python that comes with the installation and still got the same error. I had to completely reset (reformat) my machine to make it work

Comment: Worth noting that it did work if installing in WSL environment on windows. However, I had problems then opening using Putty with tunnels that were being open within WSL

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, I'd recommend you then to contact the SDK team at https://issuetracker.google.com to describe this behavior and if possible get a proper workaround for situations like this one.