# How to convert weeks of year to LocalDate

Tags: java, scala, java-time, localdate, datetimeformatter

I have a string with both year-week e.g. "2015-40" and year-month formats e.g. "2015-08", that would like to transform into LocalDate in Scala.

I have tried using

```
val date = "2015-40"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-ww") 
LocalDate.parse(date, formatter)
```

but end up with DateTimeParseException error. Would appreciate any help on how to do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you were given "2015-04" written on a piece of paper, how would you know if it meant the fourth week of 2015 or the fourth month of 2015? Simply use the algorithm that you used to answer that question to guide your programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    String date = "2015-40";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("YYYY-ww")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue())
            .toFormatter(Locale.FRANCE);
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    
    System.out.println(ld);
```

Sorry that I can write only Java, I trust you to translate to Scala. Output is:

> 2015-09-28

Why were you getting an exception? There were a couple of things missing for us to parse `2015-40` into a `LocalDate`:

- A `LocalDate` is a calendar date, and week 40 consists of 7 days. Java doesn’t know which of those 7 days you want and refuses to make the choice for you. In my code above I have specified Monday. Any other day of the week should work.
- A bit subtler. While to a human year 2015 and week 40 is unambiguous, the same is not always the case around New Year where week 1 may begin before New Year or week 52 or 53 extend after New Year. So a calendar year and a week number don’t always define one specific week. Instead we need the concept of a *week year* or *week-based year*. A week year lasts from week 1 inclusive no matter if that means it begins a few days before or after New Year. And it lasts until the last day of the last week, again most often a few days before or after New Year. To tell a `DateTimeFormatter` that we want to parse (or print) the week year we need to use upper case `YYYY` instead of lower case `yyyy` (or `uuuu`).

As an aside, if you can influence the format, consider `2015-W40` with a `W`. This is ISO 8601 format for year and week. In ISO `2015-12` denotes year and month, and many will read it this way. So to disambiguate and avoid misreading.

Edit:

In my explanation I have assumed ISO week scheme (Monday is the first day of week and week 1 is defined as the first week having at least 4 days in the new year). You may pass a different locale to the formatter builder to obtain a different week scheme.

If you are sure that your weeks follow ISO, Andreas’ suggestion in the comment is good enough that we want as part of the answer:

> Alternatively, add the [ThreeTen Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library, so you can use the
> [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html)
> class, that has a nice [`atDay​(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html#atDay(java.time.DayOfWeek))
> method for getting a `LocalDate`.

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: A great explanation for the `Year-Week` aspect of the question. Honestly, I also tried to solve this aspect in your way but got stuck at some point and then I resorted to splitting the string on `-` which is a hack in my view. Yours is the idiomatic way.

Comment: Alternatively, add the [ThreeTen Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library, so you can use the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class, that has a nice [`atDay​(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html#atDay(java.time.DayOfWeek)) method for getting a `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalDate` has three parts: year, month and day of the month. So, in the case of `year-month` string, you will have to get the `LocalDate` on a specific day as per your requirement. Parsing the year-month string is straight forward as shown in the demo code.

In the case of `year-week` string, you will have to get the `LocalDate` on a specific day of the week e.g. Mon or today's day etc. Also, instead of parsing the string directly, I found it easier to get the year and week and then use the methods `LocalDate` to get the required instance of `LocalDate`.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //#################### Year-Month #######################
        // Given year-month string
        var yearMonthStr = "2015-08";

        // LocalDate parsed from yearMonthStr and on the 1st day of the month
        LocalDate date2 = YearMonth.parse(yearMonthStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M")).atDay(1);
        System.out.println(date2);

        // LocalDate parsed from yearMonthStr and on the last day of the month
        date2 = YearMonth.parse(yearMonthStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M")).atEndOfMonth();
        System.out.println(date2);

        // LocalDate parsed from yearMonthStr and on specific day of the month
        date2 = YearMonth.parse(yearMonthStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M")).atDay(1).withDayOfMonth(10);
        System.out.println(date2);

        
        //#################### Year-Week #######################
        // Given year-week string
        var yearWeekStr = "2015-40";

        // Split the string on '-' and get year and week values
        String[] parts = yearWeekStr.split("-");
        int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int week = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

        // LocalDate with year, week and today's day e.g. Fri
        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.now()
                            .withYear(year)
                            .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfYear(), week);
        System.out.println(date1);

        // LocalDate with year, week and next Mon (or same if today is Mon)
        date1 = LocalDate.now()
                .withYear(year)
                .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfYear(), week)
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        System.out.println(date1);

        // LocalDate with year, week and today's day previous Mon (or same if today is Mon)
        date1 = LocalDate.now()
                .withYear(year)
                .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfYear(), week)
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        System.out.println(date1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-08-01
2015-08-31
2015-08-10
2015-10-02
2015-10-05
2015-09-28
```

Comment: It appears that the OP does not know, and cannot know, if it is a `year-month` string or a `year-week` string.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - OP has not mentioned whether both the values are coming from the same variable or from separate variables. I will wait for OP's comment before making any change.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution. In this case I do know when the variable will be year-month or year-week so this is a good solution